Angular Model Components using Bootstrap and popper js
I am trying to Trigger the model to open when clicking on the add tracking button in the tracking modal
<button (click)="toggleForm()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Tracking</button>

<div id="trackingModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" *ngIf="showForm">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add Tracking</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" (click)="toggleForm()"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form *ngIf="showForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="receiver">Receiver</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="receiver" [(ngModel)]="newShipmentData.receiver" name="receiver" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="price">Price</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" [(ngModel)]="newShipmentData.price" name="price" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pickupTime">Pickup Time</label>
                        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="pickupTime" [(ngModel)]="newShipmentData.pickupTime" name="pickupTime" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="distance">Distance</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="distance" [(ngModel)]="newShipmentData.distance" name="distance" required />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" (click)="toggleForm()">
                    Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


here is the traking.ts code
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { ShipmentData, TrackingService } from "../tracking.service";
import { ShipmentStatusPipe } from "../shipment-status.pipe";

@Component({
  selector: "app-tracking",
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, CommonModule, ShipmentStatusPipe],
  templateUrl: "./tracking.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./tracking.component.css"],
})
export class TrackingComponent implements OnInit {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  shipments: ShipmentData[] = []; // Temporary - adjust based on your service

  showForm = false;

  newShipmentData!: ShipmentData;

  @ViewChild("trackingModal") trackingModal!: ElementRef;

  constructor(private trackingService: TrackingService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.trackingService.getAllShipment().then((shipments: ShipmentData[]) => {
      this.shipments = shipments;
    });
    this.newShipmentData = {
      sender: "",
      receiver: "",
      price: "0",
      pickupTime: Date.now(),
      deliveryTime: 0,
      distance: 0,
      isPaid: false,
      status: 0,
    };
  }

  toggleForm() {
    this.showForm = !this.showForm;
    console.log(this.trackingModal, this.showForm);
  }

  async onSubmit() {
    try {
      // Call your service to create the shipment
      await this.trackingService.createShipment(this.newShipmentData);

      // Handle success (e.g., close the form, display a success message)
      this.showForm = false;
      console.log("Shipment created successfully");

      // Reset the form
      this.newShipmentData = {
        sender: "",
        receiver: "",
        price: "0",
        pickupTime: Date.now(),
        deliveryTime: 0,
        distance: 0,
        isPaid: false,
        status: 0,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle errors from the TrackingService
      console.error("Error creating shipment:", error);
    }
  }
}


Now when i click on the add tracking button the modal is not appearing
The flow is something like this
first the user click on the add tracking button
A model with a form will open and ask for details
when the user fill in the details it will interact with the tracking service

The modal class must also have the show class too (example)
